Yarn not enforcing Node version specified in package.json
I have this situation in which my application will not run if the Node version is below v20.
In package.json I have:
  "engines": {
    "node": "^20.10.0",
    "yarn": "^4.0.2"
  },

With that in place I can still use Node v18 and run commands with yarn, like yarn install without a warning or error. What I would like to have is that Yarn complains and throws an error. How can I enforce this?

This is a known problem with Yarn 2+, engines is handled in dependencies but not the project itself. This is inconsistent with current NPM behaviour which shows a warning on mismatched engine versions.
This can be improved by using preinstall script or Yarn plugin:
yarn plugin import https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devoto13/yarn-plugin-engines/main/bundles/%40yarnpkg/plugin-engines.js

